# How to pass parametres to an external file included by `\input{<filename>}`

Tags: macros, input, parameters

I have a class file to set up agreements. I want to define a command that

1. choose boilerplate text to include using a parameter
2. pass a parameter to the included file to run a test and choose correct
   text

In my MWE, if I invoke the command `\dispute` with the two parameters {US} and {DE}, the file `disputeUS` shall be included, and Delaware used as jurisdiction. In any other cases, New York shall be the jurisdiction. The included MWE does not work as intended. It includes the correct file, but does not pass the second parameter to the included file in a correct way. The condition is never true, and jurisdiction is always New York.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test-disputeUS}
\section{Governing law. Arbitration}
\label{sec:dispute}

The parties agree that the Agreement shall be governed by the laws of the
State of \ifstr{##2}{DE}{Delaware}{New York}, USA, without giving effect to
its principles of conflict of laws
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\dispute}[2]{\input{test-dispute#1}%
% To control the string 
\par\bigskip\noindent Control string: The state is \ifstr{#2}{DE}{Delaware}{New York}}

\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\dispute{US}{DE}

\end{document}
```

I assume there are simple solutions, but I have not been able to find them. Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Passing a parameter is possible only for a macro, not in a whole file.

Comment: So this is not possible? Is it any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, with a macro, of course. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters can be used only in the scope of a macro definition, so your `##2` in the file is meaningless.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test-disputeUS}
\section{Governing law. Arbitration}
\label{sec:dispute}

The parties agree that the Agreement shall be governed by the laws of the State of
\ifstr{\control}{DE}{Delaware}{New York}, USA, without giving effect to its principles of
conflict of laws

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\control}{}% initialize
\newcommand{\dispute}[2]{%
  \renewcommand\control{#2}%
  \input{test-dispute#1}%
% To control the string
\par\bigskip\noindent Control string: The state is \ifstr{#2}{DE}{Delaware}{New York}}

\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\dispute{US}{DE}

\dispute{US}{NY}

\end{document}
```

[image]